# Issue with aiohttp in Buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I've ran into an issue trying to convert my Kivy app to an apk using Buildozer. The app performs as intended when ran through Python, and I have no issues getting Buildozer to produce an apk. I've gone down a rabbit hole of trial and error adding all of the needed modules to the .spec file as it failed to run. Now, I am getting a new error specifically from aiohttp that has me stumped.

```
04-09 02:36:39.248 22155 23029 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-09 02:36:39.248 22155 23029 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 7, in <module>
04-09 02:36:39.249 22155 23029 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/scrython/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
04-09 02:36:39.249 22155 23029 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/scrython/cards/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
04-09 02:36:39.249 22155 23029 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/scrython/cards/autocomplete.py", line 3, in <module>
04-09 02:36:39.249 22155 23029 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/scrython/foundation.py", line 1, in <module>
04-09 02:36:39.250 22155 23029 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
04-09 02:36:39.250 22155 23029 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/client.py", line 32, in <module>
04-09 02:36:39.250 22155 23029 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/http.py", line 7, in <module>
04-09 02:36:39.250 22155 23029 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/http_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
04-09 02:36:39.251 22155 23029 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 607, in <module>
04-09 02:36:39.251 22155 23029 I python  :  TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

I'm also including the declared requirements in the buildozer.spec file. I appreciate any help figuring this out!

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,aiohttp,multidict,attrs,yarl,async-timeout,charset-normalizer,idna,scrython
```

Edit: I have tried updating the requirements above with the specific version for each used in my Anaconda environment. No change in the error out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an issue at import `aiohttp` as its' newer versions require newer versions of `async-timeout` that fails with the error (see the original [comment](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/6794#issuecomment-1180493371) by [@csira](https://github.com/csira)).
To fix this issue I pinned the next versions in `buildozer.spec`:

```
requirements = python3, kivy, aiohttp==v3.7.4, aiosignal, frozenlist, async-timeout==3.0.1, attrs, charset-normalizer, multidict, yarl, idna, typing-extensions==4.4.0, chardet==4.0.0
```