# TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str

Tags: python

TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str

my main file

```
with open("city.txt","r") as f:
    d2 = f.read()
d2=d2.strip()
if len(d2)!=0 or len(d2)!=1:
    m=d2

else:
    m="new york"
import asyncio
import python_weather
async def getweather():
    client = python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.IMPERIAL)
    weather = await client.find(m)
    for forecast in weather.forecasts:      
        with open("wx1.txt","a+") as f:
            f.write(str(str(forecast.date)+" "+ str(forecast.sky_text))
    await client.close()
```

and this is the full logcat of error

```
06-19 15:59:58.408  6609  6645 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/girlchat1/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 74, in <module>
06-19 15:59:58.410  6609  6645 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/girlchat1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Olivia/armeabi-v7a/python_weather/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
06-19 15:59:58.411  6609  6645 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/girlchat1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Olivia/armeabi-v7a/python_weather/client.py", line 1, in <module>
06-19 15:59:58.412  6609  6645 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/girlchat1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Olivia/armeabi-v7a/python_weather/rest.py", line 3, in <module>
06-19 15:59:58.420  6609  6645 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/girlchat1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Olivia/armeabi-v7a/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
06-19 15:59:58.421  6609  6645 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/girlchat1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Olivia/armeabi-v7a/aiohttp/client.py", line 32, in <module>
06-19 15:59:58.422  6609  6645 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/girlchat1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Olivia/armeabi-v7a/aiohttp/http.py", line 7, in <module>
06-19 15:59:58.423  6609  6645 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/girlchat1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Olivia/armeabi-v7a/aiohttp/http_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
06-19 15:59:58.424  6609  6645 I python  :    File "/mnt/d/girlchat1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Olivia/armeabi-v7a/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 607, in <module>
```

According to it there is a error in helpers.py at line no. 607 and below is the code for same

```
class CeilTimeout(async_timeout.timeout):


    def __call__(self) -> async_timeout.timeout:
        if self._timeout is not None:
            self._task = current_task(loop=self._loop)
            if self._task is None:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    'Timeout context manager should be used inside a task')
            self._cancel_handler = self._loop.call_at(
                ceil(self._loop.time() + self._timeout), self._cancel_task)
        return self
```

I Don't know what causing problem but any help would be great

Comment: why wouldn't you post the full error message including the stack trace?

Comment: In which line do you get this exact error?

Comment: I posted everything which is needed and I got error in class CeilTimeout(async_timeout.timeout): point at that line it gives above error and in main file it gives error on import python_weather

Answer (score 1):

I believe the last line in your main file should be indented so that it is inside the function.  This is based on the example code as found on the python-weather module page: https://pypi.org/project/python-weather/

I am assuming that the variable `m` has been defined in your main file although it is not shown in your sample.

Also, you are opening your text file inside the for loop which means that the statement will be executed on each iteration of the loop. You should open the file outside and before the loop.

Comment: updated the code and I don't think so opening the file with loop will cause any problem. The problem is it's working fine on pc but not on android

Comment: @MohitNarwani My suggestion regarding the file opening is to improve the efficiency. Opening the file in the loop may not result in an error but it will be quite inefficient as on each iteration you are opening the file, writing a line to it and then closing it. This means that if your loop iterates 10 times then you will have opened and closed the file 10 times to write 10 lines.  Moving the statement to open the file outside and before the loop will mean that the file is opened only once, the data is written out and then the file is closed after the loop has finished.

Answer (score 1):

In my case that was fixed by pinning `aiohttp` and `async-timeout` versions in `buildoser.spec` requirements (see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74214869/11284684), and the original [comment](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/6794#issuecomment-1180493371) by [@csira](https://github.com/csira))

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too, and was led here. The cause of the error was different, so I'm including this answer here.

I have a decorator, in it i expect to receive a class/func.
However, when decorating both a base class, and another class that inherits from the base class, I came across this error.

```
@deprecated("This class is deprecated. Please use NewClass instead.")
class OldClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initializing an instance of OldClass.")

@deprecated("This subclass is deprecated. Please use NewSubClass instead.")
class SubClass(OldClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

The TypeError was due to my decorator expecting a class/func, and in actuality, receiving a decorator. The fix was to handle a situation where a decorator is provided, and get the class/func that it decorates.